# How to run a script in a certain cell from button

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a cell with the contents `myFuction(param)`, I would like to run this function again when I click a button (essentially refresh this cell)

I tried setting the cell contents to "" and then setting them back to "myFunction(param)" but it returns #NAME?

SOLUTION:
Override [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events) method for cells that myFunction(param) listens to and update the cell that contained myFunction from onEdit

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refresh the function you should update it a little bit:

1. `myFunction(param,dummy)`
2. Upon calling the function, make sure you pass a dummy element as well. `myFunction(A1,"dw")`
3. To refresh, just change the dummy element's value: `myFunction(A1,"dw3")`

If you want an easier way to *refresh*, have the dummy element pointing to another cell and only change that cell's value: `myFunction(A1,B1)`. A1 would be the actual param and B1 the refresher.